# Javascript change to variable inside .then not found outside

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

Below is the code I'm trying to execute.

as described on the comment. I'm trying to have the updates to array 1 to be visible outside of .then() function.

can someone please help me understand why it happens? and how to have it visible outside of .then() function?

Thanks alot !

```
var array1 = [];    

array2.forEach(function(item) {
    // this is an async all to db.collection.findOne({_id: item.id});
    object = getObject(item.id);
    object.then(function(object) {
        array1.push(object);

        //if I print console.log(array1) here, I can see it getting updated
    });
});

// this does not print anything
console.log(array1)
```

***EDIT

Though it was a duplicate of existing question,
I was able to resolve the issue with provided example below

```
var array1 = [];    

objectPromises = array2.map(item => function(item));

Promise.all(objectPromises).then(objects -> {
    objects.forEach(function(object){
        array1.push(object);
    });

    console.log(array1);
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `console.log(array1)` gets executed before your code inside `then` callback. This is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll *have* to use a `.then` (or `await`), but it's not hard to implement:

```
const allPromises = array2.map(item => getObject(item.id));
Promise.all(allPromises).then(allObjects => {
  // do something with all objects
});
```